# Array_merge in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, array-merge

I have data I return them into collection but it does not return as i wish and i need help to fix it.

## output

```
array:11 [▼
  0 => Collection {#2762 ▼
    #items: array:3 [▼
      0 => Product {#2758 ▶}
      1 => Product {#2759 ▶}
      2 => Product {#2760 ▶}
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#2792 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  2 => Collection {#2948 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  3 => Collection {#3102 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  4 => Collection {#3216 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  5 => Collection {#2886 ▼
    #items: array:10 [▶]
  }
  6 => Collection {#2920 ▼
    #items: array:3 [▶]
  }
  7 => Collection {#3046 ▼
    #items: array:12 [▶]
  }
  8 => Collection {#3074 ▼
    #items: []
  }
  9 => Collection {#3188 ▼
    #items: array:7 [▶]
  }
  10 => Collection {#3288 ▼
    #items: []
  }
]
```

## Code

```
$category = Category::where('slug','=',$catslug)->with('childs', 'parent')->first();


$pp1[] = Product::where('category_id',$category->id)->get();

foreach($category->childs as $first){
$pp2[] = Product::where('category_id',$first->id)->get();
if(count($first->childs)> 0){
    foreach($first->childs as $second){
    $pp3[] = Product::where('category_id',$second->id)->get();
    }
}
}

$products = array_merge($pp1,$pp2,$pp3);

dd($products);
```

## What it should return

It should return all products from all arrays in 1 array only and not categorized by `Collection {#2792 ▼` I need to get only collections with items and not the ones that are empty.

Any idea?

## update

I've also tried this:

```
$pp1 = [];
      $pp2 = [];
      $pp3 = [];
      $pp1 = Product::where('category_id',$category->id)->get();

      foreach($category->childs as $first){
        $pp2 = Product::where('category_id',$first->id)->get();
        if(count($first->childs)> 0){
          foreach($first->childs as $second){
            $pp3 = Product::where('category_id',$second->id)->get();
          }
        }
      }
```

it returns:

```
array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all products of the category, of its children and of its grand-children as,

```
$category = Category::where('slug','=',$catslug)
                    ->with([
                        'products', 
                        'childs.products', 
                        'childs.childs.products', 
                        'parent'
                     ])
                    ->first()
                    ->toArray();

$products = array_merge([
    data_get($category, 'products'),
    array_collapse(data_get($category, 'childs.*.products')),
    array_collapse(data_get($category, 'childs.*.childs.*.products'))
]);
```

Fiddle : https://implode.io/ebXrD8

Comment: hi, i did not check your code yet i have no idea who down voted, i'm about to check

Comment: something isn't right about your code this is screenshot of returned data https://ibb.co/v1XyqjZ

Comment: Did you check my fiddle ? Does it have the same data structure ?